# Magento Extension - Helpful or not

Tags: magento

I am getting lot of spam searches on my website. I am giving a thought for using magneto extension  - **NoBots - Stop Magento Spam**, for blocking the spam searches.

Will it helps, or it will cause any negative impact on my website.??

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine there would be a negative impact as the fish pig extension states "By blocking these bots, your server will have fewer requests to deal with, allowing it to deal with valid customers more efficiently."

Fishpig is decent we use a few of his plugins and always find him very helpful and good value for money.

Comment: I have Installed Fishpig's - NoBots Stop Magento Spam extention to stop spam bots in my website.

Its not working..?? They are also not giving any revert for my query.

Comment: What issue are you having with it?

Comment: I am still getting those spam search bots.